# VB.NET: How to programatically create a text file in SSIS!

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I would like to create a text file with some data i am manipulating in a script component and write it to a text file.  i know how to write it to an existing text file, but what i would like to do is create the text file programmatically so i can name it `textfile(TodaysDate).txt`

How can i do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `File.CreateText(someString)`.

[This method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx) returns a StreamWriter which can be used to write to the file.
Remember to close the StreamWriter usinga `using` statement.

Comment: @Kevin: It takes a path as a parameter.

Comment: @Kevin: Then what do you think the parameter is?

Comment: @Kevin: Yes.  Did you read the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you start with a sample of the text file that you want stored somewhere, you can use a file system task to copy the sample file to the correct name (make sure you copy so that it's still there for tomorrow).  Then use an expression to set the file location in the file connection manager.